# How to push something to user in a rest API?

Tags: api, rest, notifications

We already have a system in place that uses `Restful APIs` in order to send let's say **SMS**. All of our clients are using our server to send their requests to `Rest API` so we drop connections except our server IP to handle authentication.

Now policy has been changed. We want to expose our APIs to the outside world. We now want to be able to push to user under specific circumstances. Let's say that I want to send a delivery report to the user when **SMS** has been delivered. Or when something has been scheduled for a specific time, when that time arrives user get notified.

How to handle these notifs? Has anyone used the same or similar approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can reach your clients back via HTTP. The model to do this is to use callbacks. When someone posts a scheduled job on your server, they should also post a callback URI where your server can notify when the job is complete.

Sample below:

```
https://schedulingSevrer.com/runSchedule?callback=http://clientserver.com/reportStatusHere
```

So when the job is done your callback will be like

```
http://clientserver.com/reportStatusHere?jobId=12345&status=complete
```

Or if your clients are mobile apps on Andorid you can use the Google Push notifications.

Comment: tnx. +1 Do you know any other approaches to push something to user? In web of course.